# Remote BIOS changes (My parents Live in a different City)

Tags: bios

My parents lives in some different city. The Lenovo ThinkPad (Previously IBM) TrackPoint (small [red button](http://shop.lenovo.com/ISS_Static/WW/EMEA/merchandising/options/images/large/_460_0_73P2698_V7.jpg) cursor) has some issue, so I need to disable that. If I get some remote access, is there any software through which I can also access BIOS in remote mode?

Does Software like [ammyy](http://www.ammyy.com/en/) has the capacity to stay connected in remote even though the system is not booted? or perhaps there is another such software?

Note: My parents are not a techie so they can't manipulate or make changes in BIOS that's why I need remote BIOS access.

Comment: Go visit your parents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BIOS cannot be accessed remotely for nearly all consumer devices.

**Option 1: Video Chat**

Consider using a smartphone video-chat app.  Your parents could point the camera at the screen, and you could instruct them on which option to select.

**Option 2: Disable from software**

This Lenovo article describes [how to disable TrackPoint](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht117094) from the Control Panel.  If you can get remote access to Windows, you can adjust this setting yourself.

Alternatively, it might be possible to determine how to determine how the application disables the TrackPoint.  It might be as simple as adjusting a registry setting.  Then you might be able to write an application which adjusts that setting for them.

Comment: Hmm that's the issue if somehow auto login at Gmail doesn't work they are hardly capable of accessing Gmail by inputting the password in one attempt. They are 70+ years old and hardly understand technology.

Comment: Actually as described in the Lenovo articles that you shared I already tried many hotkeys and drivers, but none were compatible and finally that [ultra nav](http://download.lenovo.com/km/media/images/HT117094/d6099a69f0914a679161398e41b87101.png) option never came even after trying 7 drivers/hotkeys. One such example of a driver that I tried [is](http://support.lenovo.com/ie/en/downloads/ds102072). Also, based on this [lenovo video](https://support.lenovo.com/ie/en/solutions/ht075599) I think bios is the only feasible option left. So I was earlier trying to get remote bios access.

Comment: I am able to find the correct driver for the m/c [Think Pad E403](http://pcsupport.lenovo.com/id/nl/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-edge-laptops/thinkpad-edge-e430/downloads/ds119266#). Finally with the team viewer session, I fixed it w/o the BIOS.